# In a regular local ring every ideal has a FFR

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $A$ be a regular local ring. Then every ideal has a finite free resolution.

My thoughts: it's easy to prove that every ideal $I$ has a free resolution. In fact $I$ is finite and there is a surjective map $$f\colon A^n\rightarrow I$$
Now $\ker{f}$ is again finite and i can repeat, but how can i prove that this resolution is definitely 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem-2.2.7 [*Cohen-Macaulay Rings* by Bruns and Herzog] Let $(R,m,k)$ be a Noetherian  local ring. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) $R$ is regular

(b) proj dim $M$ is finite for every finite $R$-module $M$

(c) proj dim $k$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a regular local ring has finite homological dimension (it is a *characterisation* of regularity). Indeed $\operatorname{dh}(A)$, the global homological dimension of $A$,  is equal to the projective dimension $\operatorname{dp}(k)$ of its residue field $k=A/\mathfrak m$, and the latter has a finite free resolution of length $\dim A$ via the *Koszul complex* since $\mathfrak m$ is generated by a regular sequence of length $\dim A$.

Comment: Ok. Then $I$ has a finite projective resolution and being in a local ring projective implies free, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm unsure whether *finitely generated* projective implies free or simply projective (the answer is an exercise of Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, ch. 2), but that's unimportant in you context.

Comment: If i recall correctly projective implies free (in local ring) but while the proof is rather easy for finite module it's a bit difficult in general